# Why image does not display only characters appears

Tags: php, mysql

I can record and display images from the database. However I'm trying to do a search through a dropdown, and then show images, but only appears characters.

Could you possibly help me saying where I am failing please?

I apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you all very much.

TEST.PHP

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","****");
mysql_select_db("Database");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function showdetails(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str==0)
  { 
 alert("Please select an Id");
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test2.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Image id:<select name="id" id="id" onchange="showdetails(this.value)">
                <option value="0">Select Image id</option>
                <?php

                $sql="select idImage from images";
                $qry=mysql_query($sql);
                $num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
                if($num>0)
                {
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['idImage'];?>"><?php echo $res["idImage"];?></option>
                 <?php
                }
                }
                 ?>
             </select>
             <div id="showresult" align="justify"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

TEST2.PHP

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","***");
mysql_select_db("Database");

$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$sql="select * from images where idImage='$id'";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($num>0)
{
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $image = $res['image'];
        header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
        echo $image;

    }

}
?>
```

[image]

But if I do a search in database with a specific id, the image shows on screen.

I can't understand where i'm failling.

I tried encode and decode 64 bur the result is the same.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","***");
mysql_select_db("database");


$sql="select * from images where idImage='201400040'";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($num>0)
{
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $image = $res['image'];
        header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
        echo $image;

    }

}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this

```
<div id="showresult" align="justify"></div>
```

with this

```
<img id="showresult" align="justify" SRC='emptyimage.jpg'/>
```

and change showdetails function to

```
function showdetails(str){
  document.getElementById('showresult').src = "test2.php?id="+str;
}
```

I am not tested this code but should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the browser it's an image. We use the `<img>` tag for that.

The image tag also needs a source. In your case. It's data:

```
<img src="data:$ActualData" />
```

$actualData should be replaced with that string. In your code that would be:

```
<div id="showresult" align="justify">
    <img id="my-image" src="" />
</div>
```

and then your javascript would change the src:

```
document.getElementById("my-image").src = 'data:'+xmlhttp.responseText;
```

### wrong solution

I think however this is the wrong solution. At this moment you are handling all the fetching of the image. something the browser can do for you... So let it handle all that.

Simply change the src of the image. and the browser will do the rest.

```
function showdetails(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str==0) { 
        alert("Please select an Id");
    }

    document.getElementById("my-image").src = 'test2.php?id='+str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this just add one column before your idImage(dont forget)
just copy this and paste this...

TEST.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("Database");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function showdetails(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str==0)
  { 
 alert("please select an Id");
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","details.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Hero Name:<select name="id" id="id" onchange="showdetails(this.value)">
                <option value="0">Select Hero Name</option>
                <?php

                $sql="select id,name from images";
                $qry=mysql_query($sql);
                $num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
                if($num>0)
                {
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['id'];?>"><?php echo $res["name"];?></option>
                 <?php
                }
                }
                 ?>
             </select>
             <div id="showresult" align="justify"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in TEST2.php   like this

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("Database");
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$sql="select * from images where id='$id'";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($num>0)
{
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
?>
<img src="foldername/<?php echo $res['photo'];?>" height="300" width="300"/>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```